# Strange Photoshop Problem: Can not select, zoom, paint, option button 'locked'

Tags: cursor, mouse, adobe-photoshop

I have a very strange problem with Photoshop. I can not use any of the tools, since the cursor appears 'locked'. If I select *v* on my keyboard, it goes to the zoom tool, but the cursor does not change. If I select the paintbrush tool, I can only paint if I hold down the *option* key.

This is what the cursor look like (I had to paint it since I couldn't capture it). It is a rectangle with two lines through it.

[image: What the cursor looks like]

I am running Photoshop CS4 on a Macbook Pro with Mac OS X 10.6.6. Using both the trackpad and an external Logitech MX5000 mouse I see the same issue.

This started when I fired up Photoshop today for the first time in a while. I can't remember changing any options or doing anything that could cause this.

Is it possible that the *option* key is somehow locked in place, or there is some equivalent of num lock on? Very strange problem, I would appreciate any help anybody can offer.

Edit: To add, the icon remains the same within all the menu options - it never goes back to being just a normal mouse cursor. Also, right click works fine, and if I hold down option, the cursor goes back to normal and I can paint with it. I can't use Marquee, Lasso, Crop, Type etc. even with option held down.

When I go into Bridge, it is the same icon.

Answer (score -1):

The cursor look a like selected path selection tool.

Restart your Photoshop than go to “Edit > Keyboard shortcuts >set > Photoshop defaults”

Repeat this same thing with Menus and then check it again. Hopefully everything will become normal in your Photoshop.

Please check this [official Adobe thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/756168) on macOS Photoshop issues.

Comment: Thanks for that tip - I am going through all of those pages now. It seems to be a common problem, which is just amazing. As soon as I get to a solution I will update this thread. Thanks again!